# Can't connect to a remote mysql database from php within a docker container

Tags: php, mysql, docker, containers

**My setup:** docker (php, mysql, nginx and some other)

**My Problem:** I can not connect to a remote mysql database within the php docker container

**php Example:**

```
    try
    {
        $this->live['pdo'] = new PDO(
            'mysql:host='.$_ENV['DB_REMOTE_HOST'].';port='.$_ENV['DB_REMOTE_PORT'].';dbname='.$_ENV['DB_REMOTE_DATABASE'],
            $_ENV['DB_REMOTE_USERNAME'],
            $_ENV['DB_REMOTE_PASSWORD']
        );
        $this->live['pdo']->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $this->live['pdo']->exec("SET NAMES utf8");
        $this->live['pdo']->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }
```

**my .env**

```
DB_REMOTE_HOST = "5.9.xxx.xx"
DB_REMOTE_PORT = 3306
DB_REMOTE_DATABASE = "somedb"
DB_REMOTE_USERNAME = "someuser"
DB_REMOTE_PASSWORD = "xxxxxx"
```

**part of my docker-compose.yml**

```
php:
build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: ./php/Dockerfile
  args:
    ENVIRONMENT: ${ENVIRONMENT}
container_name: php
restart: "unless-stopped"
ports:
  - "9000"
  - "9006"
  - "3306:3306"
volumes:
  - ./app/myapp.com:/var/www/html:cached
working_dir: /var/www/html
networks:
  - my_network
```

**So when i try to run the php example above, i am getting:**

**SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'someuser'@'85.110.xxx.xx' (using password: YES**

85.110.xxx.xx is the acutal ip address i am getting with my macbook on https://whatsmyip.com/

thats wierd for me, because the ip i try to reach is **5.9.xxx.xx**. The mysql user, the database and the password are correct i triple checked it. I can even login with sequel. I already tried to make the port 3306 public for the php container, doesn't change anything.

I will be very thankful, if anyone can help me on this.

Comment: Your `DB_REMOTE_HOST` has to be `mysql`, as you named the container as `mysql`. Docker routes the name to the internal ip.

Comment: yes that is correct if i want to connect to my local mysql container. But i want to connect to a far far away remote mysql server, outside my docker environment

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL a user is defined by a username **AND** an IP address from which they connect. There is the exceptional "%" meaning every IP is accepted. So if your MySQL user isn't defined on the server like `'someuser'@'85.110.xxx.xx'` or `'someuser'@'%'`, the server will deny access to you.

Comment: i believe no one is reading my thread properly. I don't want to connect to 85.110.xxx.xx. I want to connect to 5.9.xxx.xx

the flow is like:

-> inside docker container: trying to connect to 5.9.xxx.xx
-> Exception is thrown, that says: cant connect to 85.110.xxx.xx

i want to connect from the inside of my docker container to a foreign mysql db outside my docker environment.

5.9.xxx.xx is the correct ip of the server i'm trying to connect. 
85.110.xxx.xx is my own ip address. 

thats wierd, isnt it?

My guess it has something to do with ip4forwarding, docker and Big Sur

Comment: I believe I understood your question, but I did a bad job at explaining what I've meant. Your issue isn't a connection issue, it's an authorization issue. Simply put, your connecting IP address isn't whitelisted on the MySQL server for the user `someuser`. That's why you have to ask the administrator of the MySQL server to create the user `'someuser'@'85.110.xxx.xx'` or `'someuser'@'%'`. In MySQL a user definition is: `'username'@'allowedIP'`. You shouldn't have to make any changes to your code.

Comment: okay i get what you mean. But i can connect with Sequel to this mysql database (5.9.xxx.xx) from my macbook with my own personal IP 85.110.xxx.xx